# Create my own `PrimeQ` function

Tags: function-construction, expression-test

I want to create my own functions, for example:
Functions like `IntegerQ`,`EvenQ` and `OddQ`.

My code:

```
meuIntegerQ[_Integer] := True
meuIntegerQ[_] := False

meuEvenQ[n_Integer] /; (Mod[n, 2] == 0) := True
meuEvenQ[_] := False

meuOddQ[n_Integer] /; (Mod[n, 2] != 0) := True
meuOddQ[_] := False
```

Now I want to create `meuPrimeQ`.
How can I create my own function that verify if the number is a Prime without using `PrimeQ` obviously (like the examples).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more a math than Mathematica question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple but by far not the most efficient way is check whether any of the prime numbers $p$ numbers $2 \leq p \leq \lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor$ divides $n$ in a recursive way. In order to speed things up, I exploit *memoization*.

```
ClearAll[primeQ];
primeQ[1] = False;
primeQ[2] = True;
primeQ[n_] := primeQ[n] = Nor@@Divisible[n,Select[Range[2,Floor[Sqrt[n]]],primeQ]]
```

A test:

```
PrimeQ /@ Range[1000] == primeQ /@ Range[1000]
```

> True

It more efficient, to use short circuiting when the first divisor of `n` is found, so that non-primes have a chance to be identified quite early:

```
ClearAll[primeQ2];
primeQ2[1] = False;
primeQ2[2] = True;
primeQ2[n_] := primeQ2[n] = Block[{p = 1, b = True},
   While[b && p < Floor[Sqrt[N[n]]],
    p++;
    b = If[primeQ2[p], Not[Divisible[n, p]], True];
    ];
   b
   ];
```

A test with timings:

```
nmax = 100000;
a = PrimeQ /@ Range[nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
b = primeQ /@ Range[nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
c = primeQ2 /@ Range[nmax]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
a == b
a == c
```

> 0.039507
>
> 12.245
>
> 5.72106
>
> True
>
> True

The future runs of `primeQ` and `primeQ2` will be faster since the intermediate results have all been stored.

Answer (score 2):

@Mateus, technically satisfies your requirement! Also, unlike `PrimeQ`, does not handle `n <= 0` and non-integer n.

```
meuPrimeQ[1] = False;
meuPrimeQ[2] = True;
meuPrimeQ[n_Integer /; n > 2] := Length[Divisors[n]] == 2
```